# How to open a selected file in android?

Tags: android

In windows text files are displayed with notepad icon. When we double click the particular file it open’s the notepad and displays the file. 
Like that I need to open the file from the download folder in android. I have used the intent-filter for register my ics file’s mime type. When I select the file in the download folder it just opens my application only. At that time I need to open / read the selected file. How to do this? I am new to android Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the `Intent` your activity was fired with by calling `getIntent()`, and you can access the *data* for that Intent (in this case, likely a URI), by calling `getIntent().getData()`. Also, the *action* is likely `ACTION_VIEW`, but you probably know this already if you've set up your `<intent-filter>` properly.

Answer (score 0):

When your application is called, it is supplied an `Intent`.

You can get the file name from the intent that is supplied to your application and open the file using `new FileInputStream(String filename)`.

You can now read the data from this stream as you normally would in Java.

P.S. Make sure your application has enough permissions to access the file. You may need to declare the required permissions in your manifest.